# Is keeping weed/ganja for one time usage (for one person) a crime in India?

Tags: india, indian-constitutional-law, indian-penal-code, drugs

Is it illegal to possess an amount equal to a one-time usage for one person?

Is there any specific law for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this illegal?
YES

Is there any specific law for this? YES:

Section 20 of the [Narcotic Drugs and Psychotropic Substances Act, 1985](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_2_2_00029_198561_1517807326222&sectionId=25122&sectionno=20&orderno=24) says, *inter alia*, this:

> Whoever, in contravention of any provision of this Act or any rule or order made or condition of licence granted thereunder,--
>
> [...]
>
> - (b) ... possesses ... or uses cannabis,
>
> [...]
> shall be punishable,--
>
> - (ii) where such contravention relates to sub-clause (b),--
> - (A) and involves small quantity, with rigorous imprisonment for a term which may extend to one year, or with fine which may extend to ten thousand rupees, or with both...

Note that these are maximum sentences, and that [Section 2](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_2_2_00029_198561_1517807326222&sectionId=25100&sectionno=2&orderno=2) includes *ganja* in its definition of cannabis.